# Como usar un array en un sub diferente

Tags: excel, vba

Necesito ayuda con respecto a arrays. La finalidad del codigo es crear dos arrays cuyos tamaños serán dados por el usuario. Al tener el tamaño del array requerido por el usuario, el codigo va a generar numeros para llenar ese array.

Luego (Esta es la parte que no logro entender como hacer), el arrayA y el arrayB deben ser usados en el sub sub_A_plus_B donde se efectuará una suma de ambos arrays y se imprimirá en la misma hoja. Lo que me tiene confundida es cómo hacer para que el Sub Sub_A_Plus_B pueda usar los arrays A y B generados en el sub Sub_Input. Adjunto el codigo. Gracias por su ayuda!!

```
Public MyArrayA() As String, MyArrayB() As String, i As Integer, SizeA As Integer, SizeB As 
Integer, LengthA As Long, LengthB As Long

Public Sub Sub_Input()

Dim MyArrayA() As String 'Declare array 1
Dim MyArrayB() As String 'Declare array 2
Dim iCount As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim SizeA As Integer 'User input for first array
Dim SizeB As Integer  'User input for second array
Dim LengthA As Long
Dim LengthB As Long
Dim Multiplication As Integer

SizeA = InputBox("Inser the desired size of your first array")
SizeB = InputBox("Inser the desired size of your Second array")

Redim MyArrayA (SizeA) ' redeclares the array variable with the necessary size
Redim MyArrayB (SizeB) ' redeclares the array variable with the necessary size

 'Get size of Arrays
LengthA = UBound(MyArrayA) - LBound(MyArrayA) + 1
LengthB = UBound(MyArrayB) - LBound(MyArrayB) + 1

'Compare sizes of Array A vs Size of Array B

If LengthA <> LengthB Then
MsgBox "Both of your arrays length must be the same size and dimension. Please enter the same 
number for both arrays"

'Input sizes of arrays again
SizeA = InputBox("Inser the desired size of your first array")
SizeB = InputBox("Inser the desired size of your Second array")

ReDim MyArrayA(SizeA) ' redeclares the array variable with the necessary size
ReDim MyArrayB(SizeB) ' redeclares the array variable with the necessary size
ElseIf LengthA = LengthB Then

'Populate Array with Rand Numbers with two nested loops

For i = 0 To SizeA
 Sheet3.Range("A2").Offset(i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Norm_Inv(Rnd(), 50, 5)
Next i

For i = 0 To SizeB
Sheet3.Range("B2").Offset(i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Norm_Inv(Rnd(), 50, 5)
Next i

End If
'Call Sub Sub_A_Plus_B
End Sub
 '///////////////////////////////////////////////////
Public Sub Sub_A_Plus_B()

Dim Sum As Integer
Dim MyArraySum() As String 'Declare array 2

For i = 0 To LengthA
 MyArraySum(i) = MyArrayA(i) + MyArrayB(i)
 Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C2").Offset(i, 0).Value = MyArraySum(i)
 Next i
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Si el error es que no te deja sumar los dos arrays o que los valores del array resultado aparecen en 0, entonces el problema debe ser que nunca le asignaste los números aleatorios a los arrays en sí, sino que los imprimiste en un rango de la hoja de cálculo.

En vez de poner

```
Sheet3.Range("A2").Offset(i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Norm_Inv(Rnd(), 50, 5)
```

Deberías poner

```
MyArrayA(i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Norm_Inv(Rnd(), 50, 5)
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Me ayudó! Aunque en realidad mi pregunta concretamente es "como pasar MyArrayA y MyArrayB a Sub Sub_A_Plus_B".

Comment: Entonces me estas preguntando como pasar parámetros a los procedimientos Sub. Pues simplemente, en los paréntesis después del nombre del procedimiento, escribes ByVal en caso de que quieras pasarlo por valor o ByRef para pasarlo por referencia. Luego el nombre del parámetro y a continuación "As " y su tipo, en este caso String. Creo que para los arrays debes utilizar ParamArray en vez de ByVal o ByRef y poner paréntesis después del nombre. Y para pasar mas de un parámetro, solo separalos con comas. En la propia ayuda de Excel debe haber información mas detallada sobre esto. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

En la declaración de `Public Sub Sub_A_Plus_B()` tienes que definir los parámetros que recibirá, en este caso 2 arrays.

```
Public Sub Sub_A_Plus_B(ArrA() as String, ArrB as String)
```

Luego cuando llamas esa función, le pasas los arrays que generaste.

```
Call Sub Sub_A_Plus_B(MyArrayA, MyArrayB)
```